# Is there command aliases in django

Tags: django

I would like to ask if there's a sort of a command aliases in Django like Git does.
Because its pretty tedious to type some commands for i have a local_settings in django which leads me to type this command very often.

```
manage.py runserver --settings=local_settings
```

In Git, you can assign aliases in this manner:

```
git config --global alias.ci commit
```

Then just run

```
git ci -m "My latest commit"
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? In anything linux-based you can define aliases in your .bashrc or .bash_profile

Comment: i'm using windows 7 32 bit. I'm haven't used any linux distro yet. x(

Answer (score 2):

You can add these lines at the bottom of settings.py.

```
if 'PLATFORM' not in os.environ:
    from local_settings import *
elif os.environ['PLATFORM'] == 'TEST':
    from stage_settings import *
```

And just add some parameters that need to be overrided in local_settings.py and stage_settings.py and don't forget to create environment variable on your production and staging platform.

Now you can use normal Django command to run your server anywhere.

```
manage.py runserver
```

Comment: We use something like this, except we have a dir called `local/` and files called `local/early_settings.py` and `local/late_settings.py` (for eary/late inclusion into `settings.py`). This way the main `settings.py` file is correct *for production* and the various development/staging copies just modify as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is [django-shortcuts](https://github.com/jgorset/django-shortcuts).

Honestly i don't see a deeper sense in doing it this way (unless you are on Windows perhaps, but even there should be ways). Like cms_mgr already pointed out in his comment, aliases can be defined easily in your shell.

Here's an example from my `~./bashrc`:

```
 alias r='./manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000'
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Makefiles to define shortcuts and even chain several commands together e.g for the deployment process.

Here is an excerpt what such a Makefile could look like:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV=env
MANAGE_PY=$(VIRTUAL_ENV)/bin/python manage.py
PIP_BIN=$(VIRTUAL_ENV)/bin/pip
SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT=project.settings

all: environment requirements

environment:
    test -d "$(VIRTUAL_ENV)" || virtualenv --no-site-packages $(VIRTUAL_ENV)

requirements: environment
    $(PIP_BIN) install -r requirements.txt

createsuperuser:
    $(MANAGE_PY) createsuperuser --settings=$(SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT)

shell:
    $(MANAGE_PY) shell --settings=$(SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT)

privateserver:
    $(MANAGE_PY) runserver --settings=$(SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT)

server:
    $(MANAGE_PY) runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=$(SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT)

makemessages:
    $(MANAGE_PY) makemessages --ignore=env --all --settings=$(SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT)

compilemessages:
    $(MANAGE_PY) compilemessages --settings=$(SETTINGS_DEVELOPMENT)
```

So I can just call

```
make server
```

To start a server on LAN with my special dev settings.
And since this Makefile can be added to the git repo anyone else can use these commands as well.

(And yes we use virtualenv)